# supervisord for python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, supervisord

Want to use [supervisord](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor) to control the processes for my Python 3 project. It is specifically stated that "Supervisor is known to work with Python 2.4 or later but will not work under any version of Python 3".

Any suggestions for supervisor replacement for Python 3?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The *upcoming* 4.0 release of Supervisord [will support Python 2.7, and 3.4 and up](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/README.rst). Until then, you could use the [`supervisor-py3k` fork](https://github.com/orgsea/supervisor-py3k).

Or simply run `supervisord` with Python 2; your Python 3 codebase is otherwise unaffected, as `supervisord` is an independent process.

Comment: Thx... God the Installation gives no information and I totally don't know how to start, with so many *.py files:(

Comment: Could you add a reference for "The upcoming 4.0 release of Supervisord will support Python 2 and 3 (3.2 and up)."?

Comment: @joar: See [this issue](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/510) for a status of the Supervisord move to support Python 3.x. The master branch in GitHub supports Python 3, and is [marked as version 4.0.0-dev](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/version.txt).

Answer (score 26):

To use supervisord with Python 3 you can setup it directly with pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor
```

Comment: This is a good option as of Aug 2018, where the latest pip version is 3.3.4 versus 4.0.0dev on GitHub, as noted above

Answer (score 16):

Python 3 support for supervisord is still experimental and as mentioned in documentation, you shouldn't use it in production.

Mozilla Foundation has developed a package called [circus](https://github.com/circus-tent/circus) which works on Python 3.

It manages process with circusd and it also has circusctl, circus-top, circus-web(similar to supervisor).

You can use your supervisor conf file with circus with some changes. It also has a [seperate section in docs](https://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/rationale/#coming-from-supervisor) for users coming from supervisor. You can read that for more details.

Update:
Latest master has python 3 support. You can install it with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor
```

Answer (score 15):

Master branch of [Supervisor](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor) already supports Python3. It's a development version, so please notify any bug you find.

Answer (score 9):

supervisor 4+ supports Python3, It's available in PyPI so you can simply do `pip install supervisor` to install it.

Comment: This is the latest, should be ticked for everyone to view first.

Comment: For some reason does not works for me in Centos 6.7.  Installing it directly from github does work

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this thread, here is what I've found...

The system installed version of supervisor, installed via apt, presently is 3.3.1. This is ubuntu 18.04.

What is important to note is that the first line in `/usr/bin/supervisord` is `#!/usr/bin/python`.

This is the python 2.7 version on my system.

Looking at `https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/3.3.1/supervisor/supervisord.py`, it has `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line. This could possibly call a python3 version if it is set in the path whereby python implies python3.

However...

It appears that the install produces a stub program in `/usr/bin/supervisord` which then calls an entry point, thereby running the `supervisord.py` code.

So no matter how you set your path, how python may be set to calling a python3 program...

Its not going to get around the hard-coded `#!/usr/bin/python` call in `/usr/bin/supervisord`.

One alternative is setting up `alternatives` which results in `/usr/bin/python` being python3.

So you need to do some tracking down of how python2 and python3 are deployed on your system.