# Run celery worker on background as a daemon with AWS Elastic Beanstalk for python 3.6?

Tags: celery, python-3.6, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run celery on background as a daemon on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with python3.6.

I followed answer of this question :[How do you run a worker with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761468/how-do-you-run-a-worker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

But supervisor is not supported for python3.6 . What is solution for python 3.6.

**Note :** I am using Rabbitmq server and setup celery on my project as a remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master branch of supervisor supports Python 3. You can use it. It may have some bugs as it is in development.

To install it, run

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git
```

Ensure git installed in your system for the above command to work.

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607524/2698552), you can also use mozilla circus which is an alternative for celery.

Comment: Collecting Supervisor
  Downloading supervisor-3.3.3.tar.gz (418kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 419kB 193kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Supervisor requires Python 2.4 or later but does not work on any version of Python 3.  You are using version 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 08:44:35)
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609].  Please install using a supported version.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qexq8qt4/Supervisor/

Comment: @chiragmaliwal Can you share the command used to install? Can you try `pip install git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git
`?

Comment: supervisor installed successfully on local. But when I pushed my code to aws Eb I got the error :
Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git' while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git /tmp/pip-4vnbl4ko-build
Cannot find command 'git'

Comment: I tried both : -e git+git://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git#egg=supervisor,  -e git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git#egg=supervisor

Comment: Facing the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334158/aws-elastic-beanstalk-failed-to-install-python-package-using-requirements-txt-gi

Comment: tried but not working. Getting error ` No such file or directory: 'git' while executing command`

Comment: Thanks man! For your help.
Supervisor installed successfully .

Issue : Need to installed git on Eb.

Answer (score 0):

After one day of research finally I got the answer of my question :

Just installed git on Eb.

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Add supervisor on `requirements.txt` :

```
git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git
```

Comment: By default git is not installed on Eb.