# Unable to install Django-Channel on Django 1.11.13

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels

I am trying to install Django Channel 2.1.1 on Django 1.11.13, but getting some dependency error for the `async-timeout` package:

```
Collecting channels
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/24/f1f1ab62b4b35984d757dd1acbfed0f1c681c79e9beb4d275d18d42d4989/channels-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asgiref~=2.3 (from channels)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/dc/4cb440a69d3e26dfe430955520057c1cde51bc2fd9208215cf6b5662634f/asgiref-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: Django>=1.11 in ./djangoenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from channels) (1.11.13)
Collecting daphne~=2.1 (from channels)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/52/f82abaad9c6d8faa863b3c83d524931ae5ba737d8f91bea0bbb1c4eaf8a8/daphne-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting async-timeout~=3.0 (from asgiref~=2.3->channels)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement async-timeout~=3.0 (from asgiref~=2.3->channels) (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
No matching distribution found for async-timeout~=3.0 (from asgiref~=2.3->channels)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you [already opened an issue about this](https://pypi.org/project/asgiref/2.3.2/).

As Andrew says on the issue, the problem is that version 3 of `async_timeout` requires Python 3.5.3. He has released a new version of [asgiref 2.3.2](https://pypi.org/project/asgiref/2.3.2/) which does not require `async_timeout~=3.0`, so the install should work now.

Comment: Hello @Alasdair, I want to deploy django-channel on apache2 webserver using supervisord deamon but this package is not supporting from python 2.4, is there any alternatives available ? i also searched for monate but not fit with my configuration

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated issue so I can't help with that. Django channels is Python 3 only. Python 2.4 is *years* out of date so you will struggle to find recent libraries that support it.

Comment: Yes actually, to run web socket continuously on webserver, for that i want to use supervisord and its only support for python 2.4 and for python 3 is under development

Comment: As I said, this is a a separate issue so is off-topic for this question. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796883/supervisord-for-python-3).

Comment: Ok. let me search more on this topic. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate your help on this topic.